# Writing PDF in ASP.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I need good library for writing PDF in C#.

What I need is to put image header, write and format some text (some lines should be aligned left, some will be aligned right... to choose font, and so on) and to export it in pdf.

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp is very fully featured, but no longer 100% free and has a bit of a learning curve:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Answer (score 1):

Just Check [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) . Seems to be good one.

Provides,

1. Serve PDF to a browser
2. Generate dynamic documents from XML files or databases
3. Use PDF's many interactive features
4. Add bookmarks, page numbers, watermarks, etc.
5. Split, concatenate, and manipulate PDF pages
6. Automate filling out of PDF forms
7. Add digital signatures to a PDF file

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a library, my company has a product called DocRaptor that converts HTML to PDF using HTTP POST requests. We use Prince XML for PDF generation, and our service produces higher quality documents than similar solutions.

DocRaptor operates on a monthly subscription basis, and we offer a free plan that allows users to create up to 5 documents per month.

Here's a link to our C# coding example:

[HTML to PDF with C#](http://docraptor.com/documentation/examples_csharp)

And a link to DocRaptor's home page:

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com)

Answer (score -1):

List of open source PDF libraries

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries